# Error with XML Validation

Tags: xml, validation, w3c

I am fairly new to XML and am really having issues figuring out what I am doing wrong. Most of the errors that come back are that the document type does not allow element "track" here. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.
Please keep in mind I have been doing this for less than a month thanks in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CdCollection.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE cdCollection [
<!ELEMENT cdCollection(album)>
<!ELEMENT album(title, artist, label, disk, track+, diskOne, diskTwo)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT artist(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT label(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT disk(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT track(trackTitle, trackNumber, trackTime)>
<!ELEMENT trackTitle(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT trackNumber(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT trackTime(minute, seconds)>
<!ELEMENT minute(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT seconds(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT diskOne(title, artist, label, track+)>
<!ELEMENT diskTwo(title, artist, label, track+)>
]>
<cdCollection>
 <album>
  <title>Barenaked Ladies Are Men</title>
  <artist>Barenaked Ladies</artist>
  <label> Raisin Records</label>
  <disk>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Serendipity</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>1.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>11</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Something You&#39;ll Never Find</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>2.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>57</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
    <track>
    <trackTitle>One and Only</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>3.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>47</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Angry People</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>4.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>01</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Down to Earth</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>5.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>46</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Beautiful</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>6.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 2 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>35</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Running Out of Ink</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>7.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>58</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Half a Heart</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>8.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>27</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Maybe Not</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>9.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>00</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>I Can I Will I Do</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>10.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>08</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Fun &amp; Games</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>11.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>45</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>The New Sad</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>12.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 2 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>34</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Quality</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>13.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>15</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Another Spin</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>14.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 2 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>34</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>What A Letdown</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>15.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>49</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
   <track>
    <trackTitle>Why Say Anything Nice?</trackTitle>
    <trackNumber>16.</trackNumber>
    <trackTime>
     <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
     <seconds>42</seconds>
    </trackTime>
   </track>
  </disk>
 </album>
 <album>
  <diskOne>
   <title>Live From Mars</title>
   <artist>Ben Harper</artist>
   <label> Virgin Records US</label>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Glory &amp; Consequenc</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>1.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 6 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>01</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Excuse Me Mr</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>2.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>54</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Alone</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>3.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>01</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Sexual Healing</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>4.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>14</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Woman In You</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>5.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 8 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>00</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Ground On Down</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>6.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>39</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Steal My Kisses</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>7.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>15</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
     <track>
     <trackTitle>Burn One Down</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>8.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>53</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Mama&#39;s Got A Girlfriend Now</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>9.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 2 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>53</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Welcome To The Cruel World</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>10.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>52</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Forgiven</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>11.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 9 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>26</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Faded&#47;Whole Lotta Love</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>12.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 10 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>45</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
  </diskOne>
  <diskTwo>
   <title>Live From Mars</title>
   <artist>Ben Harper</artist>
   <label> Virgin Records US</label>
   <track>
     <trackTitle>Waiting On An Angel</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>1.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>27</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Rose From My Friends</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>2.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 5 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>36</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Power Of The Gospel</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>3.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 6 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>49</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Pleasure And Pain</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>4.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>29</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Please Bleed</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>5.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>56</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>The Drugs Don&#39;t Work</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>6.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>37</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>The Lord&#39;s Arms</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>7.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>15</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Not Fire &#44; Not Ice</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>8.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>45</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Beloved One</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>9.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 3 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>47</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Number Three</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>10.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 2 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>31</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Walk Away</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>11.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>35</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Another Lonely Day</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>12.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 4 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>48</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
    <track>
     <trackTitle>Like A King&#47;I&#39;ll Rise (Medley)</trackTitle>
     <trackNumber>13.</trackNumber>
     <trackTime>
      <minute>&#45; 10 &#58;</minute>
      <seconds>02</seconds>
     </trackTime>
    </track>
  </diskTwo>
 </album>
</cdCollection>
```

Comment: Can you get us the specific errors you're receiving instead of describing them so generally?

Comment: My main error message is " Line 27, Column 10: document type does not allow element "track" here" on multiple lines but I am also receiving  "Error Line 156, Column 9: end tag for "album" which is not finished".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re the bad end tag -- sounds like you're missing a `>` character. Look at or around line 156 of your file for a `</album>` tag and figure out how you mistyped it.

Re the validation error: You've declared

```
<!ELEMENT disk(#PCDATA)>
```

You've told it that `<disk>` should contain only untagged text. What you want is probably

```
<!ELEMENT disk(#PCDATA | track)>
```

or perhaps even

```
<!ELEMENT disk(track)>
```

if the only content other than `<track>` elements will be formatting whitespace.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content and the related sections describing DTD element declarations, or a good XML DTD tutorial.

(And you may want to consider moving from DTDs to XML Schemas, which are a more powerful way to describe a document's expected structure... unless you need to retain compatability with elderly parsers.)

Comment: Thanks for the help that cleared up most of my errors right away. I rechecked my tags and I did not mistype or misspell any of them. I am currently in a XML class and we are actually learning about XML Schemas next week.

Comment: If you're getting "bad end tag", the parser says you mistyped something, and is pointing to where. Look again. It may not be the specific error I suggested, but the document is wrong and that's where the parser discovered that it's wrong.